# DNS blocking on mobile networks?

Tags: mobile-network, mobile-data, dns

I'm using my HTC One phone on Sprint's network in NYC, and noticed that my phone cannot access Imgur.

On Chrome, when using mobile data (3G/4G):

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5hn4.jpg Fails to resolve "i.imgur.com"
- http://i.lvme.me/hjzy57l.jpg Loads fine

On Chrome, when using WiFi:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5hn4.jpg Loads fine
- http://i.lvme.me/hjzy57l.jpg Loads fine

Is anyone else seeing this sort of behavior? Might this be site-blocking at the carrier level? Or is there another technical explanation?

Any suggestions appreciated. (I'm missing my cat pictures already.)

Comment: If it "fails to resolve" the name, that's an issue with the DNS server used. While for WiFi that's easy to change via settings (in the advanced section of the APN), I never checked if/how that could be done for mobile data. If you figure out, and it can be overridden, simply replace the first DNS server entry with any open DNS server, leaving the second (of your provider) in as fallback.

Comment: I remember seeing that the DNS for mobile data can't be overridden...

Answer (score 1):

DNS can be changed with apps like "Set DNS" and with the `setprop` command, however all fail on KitKat to modify resolvers ONLY IN CASE they were set by the mobile carrier.

An simple solutions was given at:
[How to change mobile connections's DNS on Android KitKat?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62081/how-to-change-mobile-connectionss-dns-on-android-kitkat)
(in brief: put imgur's IP's in `/etc/hosts`)

It will work, but myself, I'm still hunting a way to modify the carrier's resolvers.