# How do I change my DNS on Android?

Tags: dns

I have Android 4.4.2 but this would apply to any version.

How do I change the DNS? What I would like to do is use a DNSSEC-enabled server for lookup.
Is there a 'canon' way of doing this?

Comment: Related: [How to change mobile connections's DNS on Android KitKat?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/62081/16575) Also see [other frequent questions tagged `dns`](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dns?sort=frequent).