# Change DNS but stay on DHCP

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, dns, dhcp

I have a "Minix Neo X8-H Plus" Android TV box, running Android 4.4 (KitKat).

I want to change the DNS servers on the WiFi connection, but to do that, I only get that choice if I change to a static IP address. Now, on Windows or on iOS you can keep using DHCP, while setting different DNS servers to what the DHCP service provides.

Is this at all possible on Android? Does it mean I will have to root the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment (Marshmallow) it's not possible. I usually get it using [apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=dns%20changer&c=apps) which require root permissions.

Another way could be to use an `iptables` trick, but it requires root, too.

Comment: just to confirm. you leave your ip address as dynamic(using using DHCP) and you just change the dns on the android using an app, which you need root permissions?

Comment: @HattrickNZ Yes, I do.

Comment: can you reccomend an app for changing the dns?

Comment: @HattrickNZ [I gave a similar answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/71615/61821) about KitKat devices and I explained I'm the author of one of these apps (that the one I like :))