# Where are the DNS settings stored in Android?

Tags: dns

I am using IP tables to force the system to used a specific DNS but it only seems to work for WiFi networks but not mobile data.

These are the IP tables I use:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 8.8.8.8:53
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 8.8.8.8:53
```

These commands are set to run on startup.

Apparently this is not affecting dns lookups when using mobile data?

Where are the DNS settings stored in Android?
Where does the system obtain DNS when using mobile data?

Comment: I expect that the issue you are running into is that the mobile data is not going through the NAT chain.

Comment: @davidgo Yes. Why is it happening?

Comment: Very often, NAT is applied on the outbound interface. The tunnel creates a new outbound interface which may not be matched against the IPTables.rule to do NAT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change mobile connections's DNS on Android KitKat?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62081/how-to-change-mobile-connectionss-dns-on-android-kitkat)

Comment: I don't think this is quite a duplicate, as the method that's described as not working here is one of the answers on the linked question.

Comment: `iptables` should work with WiFi and Mobile Data both. None of the IP traffic can escape `netfilter`. Also there are other ways to force DNS globally. See details here: [How to configure DNS properly?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526)